# MD5 of javascript content in WSO2 ESB API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have to deal with javascript content in API resource in WSO2 ESB. Specifically, I want to get the md5 hash from message which it is a javascript.

When I use messageType = application/javascript I get a binary, no JS message.

Can I do this? If I use binary to get md5, Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this question as given below:

At first, I changed in axis2.xml the messageBuldir and messageFormater property to "text/javascript" pointing to "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder" and "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter".

At second I got the message in API with next expression: "s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]". With that, I can save the js message in a property.

Finally, I wrote a class mediator to calculate MD5 of property with JS.